# problem while installing libmysqlclient20 on Ubuntu 20

Tags: 20.04

When I'm Trying to Run the Following command on Ubuntu 20 :

```
apt-get update
apt install mysql-server libmysqlclient20
```

I get the following error :

```
E: Package 'libmysqlclient20' has no installation candidate
```

the process is part of running some application and when i try to run the application (regardless to the error) it says :

```
 libmysqlclient.so.20: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any Help ?!

Regards

Comment: Which application says about "libmysqlclient.so.20"?

Comment: it an application called mcsql , after i check the libmysqlclient i found file under the name of "libmysqlclient.so.21.1.21" i tried to make soft link called "libmysqlclient.so.20" in the same directory ,but that didn't work . is there a way to manually install the   "libmysqlclient.so.20" ?

Comment: the one that works for me was the answer from Abraham below: https://askubuntu.com/a/1368646/1742711

Answer (score 5):

You have to install its development version (with headers) by

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

and it [will pull](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libmysqlclient-dev) correct dependency.

Comment: hi , still not working it says that the latest version is installed ! and when try to run the application it says " libmysqlclient.so.20: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu 20 replaced `libmysqlclient20` with `libmysqlclient21`, but you can still get the old version by adding an earlier Ubuntu version's repository to your apt sources, then using `apt install`:

```bsh
echo 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-security.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libmysqlclient20
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution from JellicleCat fixed it for me. Specially if you are coming from trying to get your RAILS application to work and deploy again.

```
echo 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-security.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libmysqlclient20
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by getting the file "libmysqlclient20" manually and then place it in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/"

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Just download libmysqlclient20 package from 18.04 and install it
https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libmysqlclient20/download
download link is in (security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu)